# Header moves to the right because of padding

Tags: wordpress, header, center, padding

I want my header in Wordpress to center in the body-content. Now the Page-id Div has a padding of 40px both left and right. When adding my Header in the Header.php with a width of 960 + 40 + 40 = 1040, the Header is centered within the body-content, but 40 pixels to the right, because of the padding to the left.

I placed the header within the  as an

`<img src="http://www.juristi.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/cropped-Testheader.jpg" alt="Header" height="250" width="1040" overflow="visible">`

How can my Header be fully centered within the body-content, without being affected by the padding?

The website is: [Juristi.nl](http://juristi.nl)

```
  media="all"
@media screen and (min-width: 960px)
body .site {
  padding: 0 40px;
  padding: 0 2.857142857rem;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 3.428571429rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right idea, but there's a syntax error in your code where you've specified the margin:

you have:
`<img src="http://www.juristi.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/cropped-Testheader.jpg" alt="Header" height="250" width="1040" overflow="visible" margin-left:"-40px">`

But it should be:
`style="margin-left:-40px"`

if you use it inline, or just `margin-left:-40px` if you put it in your CSS stylesheet.

Hope this helps.